# underline in datagridview

Tags: vb.net

I want to underline all items in one column. My code does not work.

`dgv.Columns(5).DefaultCellStyle.Font.Underline()`

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Are you setting that property before or after inserting a value into the cell? I am not 100% sure, but, if memory serves, this will not change the style retroactively.

Looking at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.font_members.aspx, it seems that Underline() is just a property that tells you if it's underlined. In C#, you might do

```
dgv.Columns(5).DefaultCellStyle.Font = new Font(dgv.Columns(5).DefaultCellStyle.Font, FontStyle.Underline);
```

but I don't know the VB syntax offhand.

Comment: Your second call to Columns(5).Font breaks it as returns nothing normally. This works: 
dgv.Columns(3).DefaultCellStyle.Font = New Font(dgv.DefaultCellStyle.Font, FontStyle.Bold)

Answer (score 1):

You should set the style as:

```
dgv.Columns[5].DefaultCellStyle.Font = New Font(dgv.DefaultCellStyle.Font, FontStyle.Underline)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do it for each row.
For example:

`For Each r As DataGridViewRow In dgv.Rows 
    r.Cells(5).Style.Font = New Font(dgv.DefaultCellStyle.Font, FontStyle.Underline) 
Next`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using C#, use this.

```
dataGridView1.Columns[0].DefaultCellStyle.Font = new Font(dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.Font, FontStyle.Underline);
```